# Alternative to delay function

Tags: arduino-uno, c++

I am trying to make a workaround for the delay function. I am trying to use the function in the Analog Write Mega example, by replacing delay with the function i made. However, whenever i use my function instead of delay i get incorrect led behaviour.

Here is the link to the example:

https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/AnalogWriteMega

Here is my code:

```
int currmillis = 0; //used in my function to find the current millis()
int prevmillis = 0; //used to hold previous value of currmillis
int boolval = 0;    //used to control whether to write the brightness value to the led or not
int time = 0;     //used in the delay function, difference between currmillis and prevmillis

int timeloop(int); //the function i wrote, it is at the bottom of the code

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  for ( int i = 2; i <= 13; i++)
  {
        pinMode(i,OUTPUT); 
  }
}//Setting the pins to output and allowing serial communication.


void loop (){

  for ( int thisPin = 2; thisPin <= 13; thisPin++ ) //to move from one led to the next
  { 

    for ( int brightness = 0 ; brightness <= 255; brightness++) //change the brightness of the led
    {

      boolval = timeloop(2); //the delay function returns the time passed, if the time is greater than or equal to 2, the analogWrite will write the brightness to the led

      if (boolval >= 2){ 
            analogWrite(thisPin, brightness);   
      }// if 2 ms pass, the led brightness will increase from 0 to 255 and then decrease in the following loop from 255 to 0, Once it reaches 0, the main loop moves to the next led.

    }

    for ( int brightness = 255 ; brightness >= 0 ; brightness--)
    {
      boolval = timeloop(2);

      if (boolval >= 2){ 
            analogWrite(thisPin, brightness);  
      }
    }
          timeloop(100); // a delay of 100 ms using the function
  }
}

int timeloop (int interval){ // the delay function

  do{
    prevmillis = currmillis; //hold previous value
    currmillis = millis(); //find current value 
    time = (currmillis-prevmillis); 
  }while(time < interval); 

  return time;
}
```

Thank you

Comment: Your function is a pure delay. Why do you want to rewrite it? What different behaviour do you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// You don't need to return anything since it's just a delay
// also I changed the parameters to long ints because millis()
// returns a long int
void timeLoop (long int startMillis, long int interval){ // the delay function

    // this loops until 2 milliseconds has passed since the function began
    while(millis() - startMillis < interval){} 
}

// Your call for a 2 millisecond delay would be
timeLoop(millis(), 2);
```

Also the leds may be acting weird because this schematic is wrong. As you can see one of the led's anode isn't connected to ground. It's circled in red.
[image]

If you really want it to return something you could use this:

```
long int timeLoop (long int startMillis, long int interval){ // the delay function

    while(millis() - startMillis < interval){} 
    return millis() - startMillis;
}
```

But it really isn't needed.

Comment: thank you - seems super hard to find functional functions on arduino sites

Answer (score 0):

What's the point? Why rewrite `delay()`?

Anyway:

```
int timeloop (int interval){ // the delay function

  do{
    prevmillis = currmillis; //hold previous value
    currmillis = millis(); //find current value 
    time = (currmillis-prevmillis); 
  }while(time < interval); 

  return time;
}
```

In every iteration of that loop you are updating `prevmillis`. So you will never reach the wanted delay interval.

Apart from the fact that you may as well use the inbuilt `delay` rather than writing your own, and getting it wrong.

---

> I am trying to make a workaround for the delay function

Why?

[The XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: The "Why" part interested me here, because _I'm_ in the process of changing my `delay(1000)` to a `millis()` interval. Why? because I want a more accurate timer for sending data via serial. I need the processing time to be deducted from the one second delay, so the interval between loops is as close to 1 second as possible. That's fair and achievable, right?

Comment: "W": Because I think that is more sensible than sending and displaying data at an arbitrary rate, as my application involved scheduling to real-world time. "V": So that a user can schedule an event as part of the automation program! "U": Because...    ..."F-22": Because I wasn't breast fed!... ..."M-6.8328*10^11": Because the big bang singularity occurred! "L-6.8328*10^11": Unknown.

Comment: What? Did the cat get loose on the keyboard?

Comment: lol. Do you get it? It's my extension of _"The XY Problem"_!

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you want the alternative function to do, there are a megaton of timer libraries at the [Arduino playground](http://playground.arduino.cc/Main/LibraryList#Timing). One of them is likely to provide what you need.